# Entering value to entry widget tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How do i set value to a entry widget of tkinter ?

```
Label (text='Directory').grid(row=1,column=0)
E2 = Entry(root, width=20)
E2.grid(row=1,column=1)
# Browse Button
blackbutton = Button(root, text="Browse", fg="black", command=sel_Browse)
blackbutton.grid(row=1,column=2)
```

And in the function i have the directory in

```
def sel_Browse():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
```

My question is how to five the file name to display in the E2 ?

Thanks,
Brijesh

Comment: "how to *five* the file name"? I assume that's a typo, but I can't quite tell what you were intending to write. Did you mean "find"?

Answer (score 4):

You only have to clear the content of the widget and insert the new text:

```
def sel_Browse():
    global filename, E2
    filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
    E2.delete(0, END)
    E2.insert(0, filename)
```

Alternatively, you can also [bind the entry widget with a `StringVar`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#patterns), but I think for your purpose this is simpler